# Avoiding ConcurrentModificationException while modifying multiple Maps

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, iteration, concurrentmodification

I have class containing multiple HashMaps. The values in these HashMaps are the same but the keys are different. I have to remove the same element from all Maps that contain it. The method that removes these elements takes a `Collection` as argument, iterates over it and removes elements from multiple HashMaps.
Here is the code:

```
private Map<Position, Place> map1 = new HashMap<Position, Place>();
private Map<String, List<Place>> map2 = new HashMap<String, List<Place>>();
private Map<Category, List<Place>> map3 = new HashMap<Category, List<Place>>();

public void removePlaces2(Collection<Place> places) {
    Iterator<Place> iter = places.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Place p = iter.next();
        Position pos = p.getPosition();
        String name = p.getName();
        Category cat = p.getCategory();
        map1.remove(pos);
        List<Place> list1 = map2.get(name);
        list1.remove(p);
        if (list1.isEmpty()) {
            map2.remove(name);
        }
        if (cat != null) {
            List<Place> list2 = map3.get(cat);
            list2.remove(p);
        }
        this.remove(p);
        modified = true;
    }
    revalidate();
}
```

The method throws an `ConcurrentModificationException` at the line `Place p = iter.next();`. (But not every time.) I'm at a loss as to how to avoid it. If I use `iter.remove(p)` that will only remove the element from the argument to the method: `Collection<Place> places`. And this is not what I want.
The question is how can I avoid this exception while removing the element from multiple maps?
Notice: I am not iterating over the maps from which the element is to be removed.

Comment: What are you passing it as an argument?

Comment: What does the method this.remove(p) do?

Comment: My guess is that `this.remove(p)`actually removes the place from the Collection<Place> on which you're iterating, or that this collection is one of the lists stored in map2 or map3

Comment: maybe `Collection<Place> places` is one of the `List<Place>` in `map2` or `map3`

Comment: @immibis The argument is an `ArrayList<Place>`

Comment: @Zeron You need to post more of your code, especially around the call to removePlaces2

Comment: @JamesB It's the `remove(Component)` method from a `JPanel`. The `class Place` is a subclass to `JComponent`. But this method does not affect the maps, as far as I can understand.

Comment: @Zeron Which ArrayList? Is it one that's also stored in the map by any chance?

Comment: @JBNizet 
@bayou.io If the `Collection<Place> places` is identical to one of the lists in `map2` or `map3`, how then should deal with it? Create a copy and pass it as an argument?

Comment: @immibis In some cases it may be. But not always.

Comment: you can make a copy of `places`, and iterate on the copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are passing map1, map2, or map3 as an argument to `removePlaces2()`, create a copy instead:

```
removePlaces2(new LinkedList<Place>(map1.values()));
```

If the exception persists try using thread safe versions of the maps:

```
private Map<Position, Place> map1 = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<Position, Place>());
private Map<String, List<Place>> map2 = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, List<Place>>());
private Map<Category, List<Place>> map3 = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<Category, List<Place>>());
```

Comment: Passing on a copy of the list as the argument seems to work. Thanks.